# Why is my 3em div smaller than my 3em gradient pattern?

Tags: javascript, css, font-size

I'm trying to get a random one of my green boxes turn into a red box.  I've used a gradient pattern to generate the green stripes, but my red box is smaller even they're both 3em!

```js
function getRandomInt (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var wrapper = document.createElement('wrapper');
wrapper.className = 'wrapper';
wrapper.style.cssText = "display:block;position:relative;height:100%;width:100%;";
document.body.appendChild(wrapper);

var bigholdery = document.createElement('bigholdery');
bigholdery.className = 'bigholdery';
bigholdery.style.cssText="display:block;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;height:50%;width:50%;overflow:auto;";
document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper')[0].appendChild(bigholdery);

// green bars!!!

var big = document.createElement('big');
big.className = 'big';
big.style.cssText="display:block;position:relative;height:300em;background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(.5, green), color-stop(.5, transparent), to(transparent));-webkit-background-size: 6em 6em;";
document.getElementsByClassName('bigholdery')[0].appendChild(big);

// make one red!!!

var redoffset = 3*getRandomInt(0,49);
var red = document.createElement('red');
red.className = 'red';
red.style.cssText="font-size:12px;display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:3em;width:100%;background:red;margin-top:"+redoffset+"em;";
document.getElementsByClassName('bigholdery')[0].appendChild(red);
```

```css
html{
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  font-size:12px;
}

body{
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:#BEDFED;
}

.wrapper {
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: See my answer below but why can't you create your wrapper, big and bigholdery elements in pure HTML only rather than creating them through JS?

Answer (score 1):

Your green gradient is actually 300em. See this line in your code:

```
big.style.cssText="display:block;position:relative;height:300em;
```

Comment: I know that part is 300em, but the pattern tile size is 6em by 6em, half green, half transparent.  But the red div is still smaller than half of the tile

Comment: @user2822181 - Why can't you create all the elements statically in the HTML. I think it'll help in debugging very much. I, for one, didn't even read till the end of that line. I stopped scrolling as soon as I saw 300em. Please leave a comment here with the updated codepen when you have all the elements in the HTML and the styles in CSS. You can always add some JS magic later on.

Comment: http://codepen.io/githubmaht/pen/nLmDJ Thanks Chan, I tried what you said and it fixed the problem, however, I need to generate the divs in js because I add and remove a lot of elements for a game flow.  When I generate the red div in JS, why is still smaller?  It seems it is disconnected from the html font-size attribute

Comment: wait the green ones are too big, hmmm

Comment: Here is a screenshot of how it looks on my browser. http://imgur.com/mUqvfQF. I don't find any difference in the height of red and green stripes. The only change I made was to replace the `height: 50%;width: 50%` styles with `width: 100%`.

Comment: Here is another Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJatm . This one moves a lot of styles in the JS block to CSS and only leaves margin-top there.

Comment: I see what you're doing, but the problem is I need to generate all the elements because I remove and regenerate wrapper with each level of the game.  I could move some of the static css to the css field, but this is not solving my problem.  Compare these codepens:  http://codepen.io/githubmaht/pen/jinHo http://codepen.io/githubmaht/pen/nLmDJ